# On Windows 7, how can I assign languages (German/English) to user accounts?

Tags: windows-7, language, english, german

I would like to have **two** user accounts on my laptop: one for a **German** speaker and one for an **English** speaker.  Are **language packs** far enough advanced now that I can just:

- download a Germany language pack
- install it
- assign a user account to it

so that the operating system language changes based on who is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any language packs installed at the moment so some wording may be wrong.

Language packs are installed for all users but the preference of which language should be used is per user so it's possible to do what you ask for.

1. Download and install the language pack.
2. Log in to the user you want to have german menus.
3. Go to region and language options.
4. Go to Keyboards and Languages.
5. Select German.
6. Log out and in again and you're done.

All of this applies to Vista as well.